# Java - How to make a line break every n repetitions in a loop

Tags: java, loops

My code prints every number between two limits and makes a sum. 
How can i print a new line every 10 numbers?

```
for (int i = nedreGrense; i <= øvreGrense; i++) {           
        sum = sum + i;            
}
for (int tallStreng = nedreGrense; tallStreng < øvreGrense; tallStreng++){
    System.out.print(tallStreng+"+");
}
System.out.print(øvreGrense+"="+sum);
```

Comment: `if(tallStreng%10 == 0) {System.out.println();}` Inside your loop

Comment: @GBlodgett `edreGrense` can be any `int`so your solution will not work if for example `edreGrense =12 `

Comment: Just write your question as code: add counter variable. Increase counter at every number, and if counter equals limit, then print newline and reset counter.

Comment: @hyde why he needs counter? you see my answer?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod Because it separates the logic of printing newlines from the mathematical range of numbers. Changing one then does not affect the other (for example, have other series of numbers than range with increment of 1).

Comment: `(tallStreng != nedreGrense) && ((tallStreng - nedreGrense)%10 == 0)` also does not affect the numbers, so i think adding another counter is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Since your limits can be any integer, so if `nedreGrense` can be any `integer`, 
then after `nedreGrense` increases by 10, its ones will not change only its tenth will change, to check we have to use `%` operator which gives ones of the number.

So use the condition `if( (tallStreng != nedreGrense) && ((tallStreng - nedreGrense )%10 == 0))`

```
for (int i = nedreGrense; i <= øvreGrense; i++)
        sum = sum + i;    
    for (int tallStreng = nedreGrense; tallStreng < øvreGrense; tallStreng++){

        if( (tallStreng != nedreGrense) && ((tallStreng - nedreGrense)%10 == 0))
          System.out.println();
        System.out.print(tallStreng+"+");
    }
    System.out.print(øvreGrense+"="+sum);
```